# Reading JSON datetime into C# - DateTime not pulling through correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Note* I know the second method has a different name but 'GetConsignmentByStatusId' method just pass it on to 'GetExportConsignment' without doing anything.

Im getting different datetimes in .Net C# class when passed over a service from a MVC application. I have searched before but I'm unfamiliar with JSON so not too sure what I need to be looking at

Here is the MVC code that calls the service. The 'ConsignmentSearch' object is causing the problem. So here it gets serialized.

```
public IEnumerable<ConsignmentInfo> LoadConsignmentByStatusId(int userId, int companyId, string language, int statusId, int pageNumber, int pageSize, ConsignmentSearch search)
    {
        IEnumerable<ConsignmentInfo> consignmentInfo = null;
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonInput = serializer.Serialize(search);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = Client.PostAsync(
            string.Format("Consignment/GetConsignmentByStatusId?userId={0}&companyId={1}&language={2}&pageNumber={3}&numRecs={4}&statusId={5}", userId, companyId, language, pageNumber, pageSize, statusId)
            , content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            consignmentInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ConsignmentInfo>>().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
        return consignmentInfo;
    }
```

Then this is part of the code in the service. There are 2 datetime fields in this object
that is always different as from what is passed on. What would I need to do to read the correct dates? any help or links would be appreciated.

```
public static IEnumerable<ConsignmentInfo> GetExportConsignment(int userId, int companyId, string locale, ConsignmentSearch search, int pageNumber, int numRecs, int statusId)
    {

        var consignmentStatusList = new List<ConsignmentInfo>();
        SQLDataAccess db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(GlobalsManager.DbConnectionString) as SQLDataAccess;
        DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Logistics.spGTSConnectGetExportConsignment");

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "UserId", DbType.Int32, userId);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "CompanyId", DbType.Int32, companyId);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Locale", DbType.String, locale);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.ConsignmentNumber))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "ConsignmentNumber", DbType.String, search.ConsignmentNumber);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.HouseWaybillNumber))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "HouseBillNumber", DbType.String, search.HouseWaybillNumber);
        }
        if (search.DateOfLoadingFrom != null)
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "DateOfLoadingFrom", DbType.DateTime, search.DateOfLoadingFrom);
        }
```

Comment: How are the values in JSON and how are they in the service parameters?

Comment: Here is the JSON for the two dates (1 Jan 2014 to Jan 10)  l,\"DateOfLoadingFrom\":\"\\/Date(1388527200000)\\/\",\"DateOfLoadingTo\":\"\\/Date(1389304800000)\\/\",    ....And here is the from date - {2013/12/31 10:00:00 PM} and here is the To Date - {2014/01/09 10:00:00 PM}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and here it is

I added the following method

```
 JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };
```

and then change the LoadConsignmentByStatusId method to this

```
 public IEnumerable<ConsignmentInfo> LoadConsignmentByStatusId(int userId, int companyId, string language, int statusId, int pageNumber, int pageSize, ConsignmentSearch search)
        {
            IEnumerable<ConsignmentInfo> consignmentInfo = null;
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search, microsoftDateFormatSettings), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using JS to request/send data to your service, you can use the following script to fix dates on JSON:

```
function convertJsonDate(dateString) {
    var date = new Date(dateString.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    var dd = date.getDate()
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1  // now moths are 1-12
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm
    var yy = date.getFullYear()
    if (yy < 100) yy = '20' + yy

    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy;
}
```